# How can I strip the .gopclntab and (optionally) the .gosymtab sections of my Go binary?

Tags: go, binary, compiler-optimization

I program on Linux x86_64. I run `readelf -S ./mybinary` and I see that the Go compiler places these two sections called `.gopclntab` and `.gosymtab` in the binary. It seems that at least `.gopclntab` is not necessary at runtime. I happened to find [this article](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/programming/GoBinaryStructureNotes) which confirms that:

> Unfortunately, Go binaries that use cgo do not have these Go ELF
> sections. As mentioned in [Building a better Go linker](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1D13QhciikbdLtaI67U6Ble5d_1nsI4befEd6_k1z91U/view):
>
> For “cgo” binaries, which may make arbitrary use of C libraries, the
> Go linker links all of the Go code into a single native object file
> and then invokes the system linker to produce the final binary.

So apparently these are not strictly necessary for the program to run properly. However, the `strip` utility doesn't strip them, likely because it is not aware of these Go-specific sections. Note that even if I use `go build -ldflags="-s -w"`, these sections still exist.

Is there a way to strip them aside from using `cgo`?